# Virtual machine pauses at random intervals

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

Some of my virtual machines (using MS Virtual PC) recently started to show a very annoying behavior: from time to time (at random intervals) the virtual machine pauses/freezes for one minute. During these pauses, I can't do anything in the virtual PC.

- The host system is Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit). The machine is quite powerful, and the problem ocurrs even when nothing is running on the host.
- The guest system is Windows XP. It has 1500 MB of memory assigned to it.

Any ideas how to diagnose this problem and find the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

My gut instinct tells me a possible hard drive issue in the host machine.  With the current cost of drives, it shouldn't be too expensive to get another drive and clone it. In most cases in which I have experienced or had clients that experienced similarly sporadic behavior in a similar situation, shortly after they had hard drive failure and were screwed with no backups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have never experienced any problems with that disk from the host system. But anyway, I have now moved my virtual PCs to the other disk (SSD) and will watch if the problem has gone away.